# Android App's Data size increasing Does Glide cause this?

Tags: android, android-glide

Android apps data size is increasing like 13MB when i opened and loaded few(100) images using glide library. I haven't managed any caching properties of glide, all set to default. Is there any chance disk caching of glide cause this problem?

NB:Images are of 100Kb size range.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can clear Glide  library memory ondestroy of your activity or fragment

```
@Override 
public void onDestroy() {

super.onDestroy();
Glide.get(this).clearMemory();
}
```

**Skipping Memory Cache**

skipMemoryCache( true ) to specifically tell Glide to skip the memory cache.when you call load add that property like this

```
Glide  
.with( context )
.load(url)
.skipMemoryCache( true )
.into( imageViewInternet );
```

**Skipping Disk Cache**

```
Glide  
.with( context )
.load( url)
.diskCacheStrategy( DiskCacheStrategy.NONE )
.into( imageViewInternet );
```